# How Can I prevent duplicate change text file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have successfully changed text in linux using this shell script

```
vi -e .bash_profile << END
i
PATH=\$PATH:\$HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin
export PATH
PGDATA=/usr/pgsql-9.4/data
export PGDATA
.
w
q
END
```

but I have a problem.

If I execute script twice then duplicate in text file.

So, I want to prevent this situation. How Can I fix it?

Comment: Why not use `sed -i` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that depends... if the string `"PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin"` can appear at other places in side the file then we could not use it as an indicator that your vi has already done its work. But if the string otherwise does not appear we could wrap the whole thing

```
grep -q 'PATH=[$]PATH:[$]HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin' .bash_profile
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
   # do your vi stuff here
fi
```

You might replace the if stuff by

```
test $? -eq 0 && exit 0
```

if you were not going to do anything after the vi stuff